# Creation of temporary long double variable

Tags: c++

Consider following code:

```
double d1 {123.123};
double d2 = 123.123;
double {123.123};

long double ld1 {123.123};
long double ld2 = 123.123;
long double {123.123}; // (X)

template <typename T>
void boo (T v) {}

boo<long double> (123.3123);
boo (long double {123.3123}); // (Y)
```

In both examples (X) and (Y) GCC 5.2.1 produces

`error: expected primary-expression before ‘long’`

Could someone explain me, why this error occurs?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, in C++ you must give a name to your variables:

```
long double dont_have_name {123.123}; // (X)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Secondly, in C++ you can't do this:

```
boo<long double>(long double {123.3123}); // (Y)
```

is not a valid syntax. You could this:

```
boo<long double>(123.3123);
```

where floating point literal `123.3123` will be converted to `long double` due to the explicit template argument.

Or you could take advantage of template argument deduction for template functions with explicitly casting the input argument to `long double` via `static_cast`:

```
boo(static_cast<long double>(123.3123));
```

or you could specifically mark your input argument as `long double` literals by postfixing them either with `L` or `l`:

```
boo(123.3123L);
boo(123.3123l);
```

[*Note: that if you put only `123.3123` as input argument above then due to template argument deduction rules `T` is going be deducted as `double` due to the fact that floating point literals are by default of type `double`.*]

Comment: No, I don't. Look at the third line - it compiles. I didn't write `boo<long double>{123.3123};`

Comment: `123.3123L` produces a correctly rounded `long double` value while `static_cast<long double>(123.3123)` simply upcasts the `double` value

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Could you please elaborate? I don't get your point.

Comment: 123.3123L will be more precise in long double precision. Just like `123.3123f` is more correct when assigning to a float than `(float)123.3123`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc are you sure about that? because here we have well defined literals.

Comment: `123.3123f` is `0x1.ed3fccp6`, `123.3123` is `0x1.ed3fcb923a29cp6` and `123.3123L` is `0x1.ed3fcb923a29c779a6b4p6` (assuming Intel 80-bit extended precision) while `(long double)123.3123` will be `0x1.ed3fcb923a29cp600000p6`. This has been discussed so many times in floating-point related questions

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Are you suggesting that up-casting a double literal to a long double literal via static_cast implies loss of accuracy?

Comment: no. there's no loss of accuracy but the result might not be as one expected.